# Вконтакте API (вернуть id группы, по имени)

Tags: вконтакте, javascript

Нашел функцию, но нихрена не получается с ней работать.

Короче, задача поставить виджет сообщества, который должен меняться, в зависимости от имени группы.

Стандартный код этого виджета:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    VK.Widgets.Group("vk_groups", {mode: 1, width: "360", height: "290"}, 20003922);
    </script>
```

Где **20003922** - **айди** группы.

Допустим юзер зашел, дал мне ссылку в формочку своего сообщества, к примеру - **http://vk.com/typical_proger**

Как узнать айди этой группы, чтобы вставить?

Я нашел функцию, вот она - http://vk.com/developers.php?oid=-1&p=groups.getById
но нихрена не получается с ней работать.

Что я делаю не так?

**UDP:**

Что надо сделать? Вот есть ссылка на сообщество. она может быть любой, ну к примеру вот: http://vk.com/typical_proger

**Как узнать id этой группы?**

Comment: А что именно не получается то?

Comment: читайте ниже UDP

Comment: Вы забыли заключить название группы в кавычки! Очевидно, что переменная typical_proger действительно is not defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ранее не работал с Вконтакте API, но могу сказать одно, может поможет вам. Нажмите на название блока группы "Видеозаписи" или "Подписчики"  - и результат:  id группы "typical_proger" -  **30666517**

Answer (score 0):

```
ID групп, перечисленные через запятую, информацию о которых необходимо получить. В качестве ID могут быть использованы короткие имена групп. Максимум 500 групп.

 <script type="text/javascript">
    VK.Widgets.Group("vk_groups", {mode: 1, width: "360", height: "290"}, typical_proger);
    </script>
```

Вообще без проблем!

Comment: так не работает - http://likebox.ru/qr/cupon.html
В консоли пишет typical_proger is not defined

Answer (score 0):

а так пробовал?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        VK.Widgets.Group("vk_groups", {mode: 1, width: "360", height: "290"}, typical_proger);
</script>
```

Comment: так не работает - http://likebox.ru/qr/cupon.html В консоли пишет typical_proger is not defined